# Mysql 5.7 dont use index

Tags: mysql, indexing, percona

Hello since i update from mysql 5.5 to percona 5.7

This query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(a.alarm_id) AS `count`, MAX(a.alarm_id) AS `max_alarm_id`, `a`.`priority` 
    FROM `alarm` AS `a` 
    WHERE (a.maintenance_suppress = '0') 
    AND (a.deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
    AND (a.object_id = '6') 
    GROUP BY `a`.`priority`
```

Wont use indexes as expected any more.

This is the explain for the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                       | key       | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ref  | maintenance_suppress,alarm_count,deleted_at,object_id,alarm_count_b | object_id | 10      | const,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this are my indexs:

```
Keyname                 Type    Unique  Packed  Column                      Cardinality Collation   Null
PRIMARY                 BTREE   Yes     No      alarm_id                    1156170     A           No  
quited_by               BTREE   No      No      acknowledged_by                  78     A           Yes 
deleted_by              BTREE   No      No      deleted_by                        9     A           Yes 
device_id               BTREE   No      No      component_id                    820     A           Yes 
message_status_create   BTREE   No      No      message_status_create             2     A           No  
leaved_at               BTREE   No      No      leaved_at                    597481     A           No  
                                                message_status_leaved        527117     A           No
acknowledged_at         BTREE   No      No      acknowledged_at              139029     A           No  
                                                message_status_acknowledged  176719     A           No
maintenance_suppress    BTREE   No      No      maintenance_suppress              1     A           No  
ticket_id               BTREE   No      No      ticket_id                         1     A           Yes 
alarm_count             BTREE   No      No      priority                          5     A           No  
                                                specified_class                   8     A           No
                                                maintenance_suppress              8     A           No
                                                deleted_at                    27340     A           No
                                                object_id                     21310     A           No
deleted_at              BTREE   No      No      deleted_at                    29538     A           No  
specified_class         BTREE   No      No      specified_class                   2     A           No  
created_at              BTREE   No      No      created_at                   876796     A           No  
object_id               BTREE   No      No      object_id                       192     A           No  
                                                deleted_at                    10261     A           No
                                                maintenance_suppress          56175     A           No
alarm_count_b           BTREE   No      No      priority                          6     A           No  
                                                maintenance_suppress              9     A           No
                                                deleted_at                    31421     A           No
                                                object_id                     46226     A           No
```

If i force the index it is going to be slower:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(a.alarm_id) AS `count`, MAX(a.alarm_id) AS `max_alarm_id`, `a`.`priority` 
    ->     FROM `alarm` AS `a` 
    ->     WHERE (a.maintenance_suppress = '0') 
    ->     AND (a.deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
    ->     AND (a.object_id = '68') 
    ->     GROUP BY `a`.`priority`;
+-------+--------------+----------+
| count | max_alarm_id | priority |
+-------+--------------+----------+
|     8 |      1278404 |        2 |
+-------+--------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(a.alarm_id) AS `count`, MAX(a.alarm_id) AS `max_alarm_id`, `a`.`priority` 
    ->     FROM `alarm` AS `a` FORCE INDEX (alarm_count_b)
    ->     WHERE (a.maintenance_suppress = '0') 
    ->     AND (a.deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
    ->     AND (a.object_id = '68') 
    ->     GROUP BY `a`.`priority`;
+-------+--------------+----------+
| count | max_alarm_id | priority |
+-------+--------------+----------+
|     8 |      1278404 |        2 |
+-------+--------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.67 sec)
```

Has anyone a idea what is wrong with my indexs?

SQL fiddle to play arround:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23949/1

Comment: Your query does uses indexes according to the explain. What indexes did you expect it to use (alarm_count_b perhaps?)? Has the execution slowed down significantly since the migration?

Comment: Yes i would expect alarm_count_b and it slows down extreamly. By factor 30

Comment: Have you tried using index hint (force index) in your query?

Comment: Also, you can force mysql to update the index stats by running anlyse table command.

Comment: Force index is going to be slower, analyse table dont helps at all. I add a sqlfiddle for you to playaround

Comment: Why would force index be slower? SQLfiddle will not help in this case, since each mysql instance and version will make its own choices.

Comment: Suspect the reason the upgrade might have had an effect is that it has done an ANALYZE TABLE when doing the upgrade, hence now choosing an index from updated statistics. The index it is using now does seem more logical for the columns you have in the WHERE clauses, but possibly try adding priority as an extra column at the _end_ of the object_id index.

Comment: @Kickstart: Thanks "Using where; Using index" write this as answer to get points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect the reason the upgrade might have had an effect is that it has done an ANALYZE TABLE when doing the upgrade, hence now choosing an index from updated statistics.

The index it is using now does seem more logical for the columns you have in the WHERE clauses. All 3 columns in the index are used in the WHERE clause. The alarm_count_b index has the column used for the GROUP BY at the start of the index, yet this is only really useful once records have been excluded by the WHERE clause.

However try adding priority as an extra column at the end of the object_id index.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said what it 5.5 did versus 5.7.  In any case, you do not have the optimal index, so I will answer that issue instead.

```
WHERE (a.maintenance_suppress = '0') 
AND (a.deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
AND (a.object_id = '6') 
GROUP BY `a`.`priority`
```

begs for `INDEX(maintenance_suppress, deleted_at, object_id, priority)` in any order, except that `priority` must be *last*.  Suggest you add `priority` to `INDEX object_id`.

As a general rule, *start* with `=` conditions, then move to *one* range condition in the `WHERE`.  If the `WHERE` is completed, then the *one* range can be all the fields of either `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.

[More discussion of index building](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Another note.  Assuming you are using InnoDB, `alarm_id` will be part of that index, thereby making it "covering".  This gives an extra boost.  `alarm_count_b` is also covering, but the columns are not arranged in an optimal order, hence the poor performance.

Without seeing your other queries, I cannot judge the rest of your indexes, other than to say 14 indexes is "a lot".